# How to convert Vector to JSON array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to pass a vector from a java class to a JSON array. Because I'm passing it to localStorage it's supposed to appear as a string.

```
"[thisisastring,thisisalsoastring,morestrings,onelaststring]"
```

so far I have...

```
<% myJavaClass mJC = new myJavaClass(); %> // the constructor
```

and this line...

```
"<%= mJC.getVector() %>"
```

passes the vector I want to turn into a JSON Array. I haven't really used JSON before so I'm not sure what I'm doing. I assume I'd create a new array but how would I populate it?

Comment: The Java String you have there almost is a JSON array.  All you're missing is quotes around the string values.  But a better way to construct a JSON string, in the general case, is to create the Maps and Lists that represent it and use a JSON "serializer" to convert those to the JSON string.

Comment: Make use of these : http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-json-tutorials/ . They are handy .

Comment: Do you have your code for `myJavaClass()` ?

Comment: You should use a library but a json array of strings is so easy to build 'manually'...